# Is there any generic oauth2 library for Android that can work with different providers (google facebook github)?

Tags: android, oauth

Im looking for oauth2 library that could create Authorization dialogs for multiple oauth2 providers.

Answer (score 0):

This one should be able to:

http://code.google.com/p/google-oauth-java-client/downloads/detail?name=google-oauth-java-client-1.8.0-beta.zip&can=2&q=

Here's a few docs:

http://code.google.com/p/google-oauth-java-client/wiki/OAuth2

The AuthorizationCodeFlow section gives you a few pointers.